# How to implement CSRF referer check in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, csrf, owasp, referer

I would like to use the simplest method of protecting against CSRF, which is to check the referer header as per OWASP's [CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet - Checking Referer Header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header). What is the correct way to implement that in a java servlet? Would something like this work?

```java
    String requestUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    // we expect the referer to "start with" at least up to the hostname of the current request url
    String expectedRefererStartsWith = request.getRequestURL().substring(0, requestUrl.indexOf('/', 9));
    String referer = request.getHeader("referer");

    return referer != null && referer.startsWith(expectedRefererStartsWith);
```

Note that I realize referer check is not the most foolproof method of CSRF (could cause problems if browser or network device is blocking the referer header), but for this particular app it will be fine.

Comment: The number 9 is so that it won't match the `//` from `http://` or `https://`. Perhaps instead of 9 I should use `"https://".length()`